# Using smarty to assign multidimensional array

Tags: php, smarty

I have the following xml which I'm accessing through simplexml:

```
<sequences>
    <sequence>
        <ImageUrl id="">
            http://www.image.com/image.jpg
        </ImageUrl>
        <photographer>name</photographer>
    </sequence>
    <sequence>
        <ImageUrl id="">
            http://www.image.com/image1.jpg
        </ImageUrl>
        <photographer>name 1</photographer>
    </sequence>
</sequences>
```

I need to pass this data to smarty and output in a template. I need to be able to output the first sequence image and photographer name and then the second. How can I do this? I can see that you can pass an array to smarty and then loop over it in the template but I essentially need to pass a multidimensional array, 1 array for each sequence node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up assigning the whole simplexml obj to a smarty and looped over it like to in the template:

```
{foreach from=$contents key=key item=item}
    {foreach from=$item key=k item=i}
        {if $k eq 'ImageUrl'}
            <img src="{$i}" />
        {/if}
        {if $k eq 'photographer'}
            <img src="{$i}" />
        {/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your XML to array then :

In php

```
<?php
$arr = array("first"=>1000, "second"=>1001, "third"=>1002);
$smarty->assign('myArray', $arr);
?>
```

In smarty template :

```
<ul>
{foreach from=$myArray item=myArray name=myArray}
    <li>{$myArray.first}</li>
    <li>{$myArray.second}</li>
    <li>{$myArray.third}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Comment: no, I need to be able to output the first sequences image and name and then the second seperately

Comment: Then pass images in different variables instead of a single array, pass these variables to smarty, and echo it using {$var}

Comment: but there could be an arbitrary number of sequence items so that will never work